# What is the white bar above stamina for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every now and then I see a thin white bar that appears above my stamina bar.

It began at full and ever so slowly it's crept down to about halfway.

It only appears sometimes, and I'm not sure what I'm doing to make it show up.

What is it?

(I'll try to get some pictures soon if no-one can figure out what I'm talking about.)

Comment: Are you using an enchanted weapon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thus white bar is the charge left in your enchanted weapon (above stamina for right weapon, above magicka for the left) Each time you attack with your weapon, it use a charge, and the bar get more empty.

To add charges to your weapon, you first need a soul gem with a soul inside. Then, you must go in the inventory, select your weapon, then press the T key, select your soul gem, and your weapon should have more charges.